# With SQL trying to identify rows that start with 10 digits

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a `EMAILADDRESS VARCHAR2` field in my table `LOCMEMBERS`. Some email address start with a 10 digit phone number, and I am trying to identify those that do. So I am looking for a way to flag `5556667777@vtext.com` but not `10JamesDean@vtext.com`.

This is an Oracle DB.

I tried the following, but the `SUBSTRING` throws an error "*invalid identifier*":

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(EMAILADDRESS AS VARCHAR(20)), 1, 10),         
FROM LOCMEMBERS
```

Comment: Did you try searching for `Oracle substring`?

Comment: `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(EMAILADDRESS, '^[[:digit:]]{10}' )`

Comment: If `EMAILADDRESS ` is already a `varchar` there is no sense in casting it into one

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WITH
 locmembers(member_id, email_address) AS
 (SELECT 1,'12345@rrr.com' FROM dual UNION ALL   --numbers but < 10 digits
  SELECT 2,'1122334455@rrr.com' FROM dual UNION ALL  --numbers = 10 digits
  SELECT 3,'112233445566@rrr.com' FROM dual UNION ALL  --numbers > 10 digits
  SELECT 4,'emailaddress@rrr.com' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,'emailsaddress1122334455@rrr.com' FROM dual   --email address with 10 digits
 )
SELECT
 member_id
,email_address
,SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(email_address, '^[[:digit:]]{10}' ),1,1)
FROM
 locmembers
WHERE SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(email_address, '^[[:digit:]]{10}' ),1,1) = '@'
;
```

Comment: @Alex K. - I updated my answer to incorporate your cleaner use of REGEXP

Comment: Thanks, got it working with this:  SELECT
 member_id
,email_address
FROM
 locmembers
WHERE SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(email_address, '^[[:digit:]]{10}' ),1,1) = '@'